# Citizen of Moldova travelling to Finland as an interpreter on a short business trip (7 days) - visa exemption

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, business-travel, finland, moldovan-citizens

I am a citizen of Moldova and I plan to travel to Finland from Turkey, where I currently reside, as an interpreter for two people on a business trip. I am a freelance interpreter, so I am not a registered employee of the company whose representatives I will be traveling with.

Under the current travel regulations Moldavian citizens do not require a visa for short visits to the Schengen area. However I am worried about whether my visit purpose is covered by the visa exemption. Should I mention that I travel as an interpreter to the immigration officer at the border? If I do, could there be any issues?

I will be able to provide proof of accommodation, return tickets etc.

Comment: Both Schengen and the UK allow personal services like body guards and translators and etc etc to accompany and do their work, but not work for anyone else.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be fine. If you're asked, you should mention that you're working as an interpreter and that's the reason for your stay. There shouldn't be any issues since interpreters are free to work without visa.

[The Ministry for Foreign Affairs of Finland](http://www.formin.fi/public/default.aspx?contentid=182948&nodeid=15720&contentlan=2&culture=en-US) states that you don't need a visa.

And, according to [Finnish Immigration Service](http://www.migri.fi/working_in_finland/right_to_work_without_a_residence_permit), Finland allows interpreters to work without a residence permit for a stay maximum of 90 days.

> You do not need a residence permit for an employed person or any other
>   residence permit in the following cases:
>
> if you are an interpreter, a teacher, a specialist, or a sports judge
>   or referee, you work on the basis of an invitation or a contract, and
>   the duration of the job is no longer than 90 days